# How to run iso-tex2iso in batch mode?

Tags: latex, osx, character-encoding, tex

**Main question:**
In order spell checkers can apply, `M-x iso-tex2iso` is nice for converting `TeX`-encoded files to e.g. `UTF-8` encoded ones. But, in case a numerous files to convert, running this command in a batch mode would be helpful. How to do that?

**Subsidiary question:** (not for me, for a friend of mine owning a Mac) On OSX, how to make this batch thing a script with an associated icon that could "receive" (by "drag and drop") a file to be converted?

Comment: I don't know how exactly `iso-tex2iso` works, but I'm certain of that you can run Emacs in batch mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html - it could be enough for your task as is, or maybe you will need to write a wrapper function to feed the data to `iso-tex2iso`. Of course you could also do it from Emacs interactively too with either macros or some Elisp code - depends on your actual requirement.

Comment: Also, studying how `batch-byte-compile` does it's job could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to wvxvw's comment, I can answer my own (main) question: in order to convert a `TeX`-encoded file, say `foo.tex`, into an UTF-8 encoded one, it is enough to run (no need to open the file in `emacs`):

```
emacs -batch foo.tex -f mark-whole-buffer -f iso-tex2iso -f save-buffer -kill
```